# How to write SQL Server query to pull date that are coming in 3 month?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have column that has expiration date and I would like to pull expiration date that are coming within 3 month.

```
WHERE DATEDIFF(month, t5.warrantyexpirydate, GETDATE()) <= 3
```

or

```
WHERE t5.warrantyexpirydate >= DATEADD(month, 2, GETDATE())
```

Both of these where statement pull any items that are greater than 3 months. Can anyone help me with this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `>=` and `<=` logic, as it's SARGable when you don't apply functions to your column:

```
WHERE warrantyexpirydate >= DATEADD(MONTH, -3, GETDATE())
  AND warrantyexpirydate <= GETDATE() --This isn't needed if the expiry can't be in the future
```